# Add icons inside textbox area onfocus event, using bootstrap and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anybody knows how can I add some bootstrap icons to my textarea. Icons should show on focus and hide on focus out. This textarea is similary, if not the same as Facebook Add new status textarea.

All I was able to do is to expand and shrink textarea onfocus/focusout events, using JavaScript.

This is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="height:150px">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <textarea class="expand" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500);
    });

    $('textarea.expand').focusout(function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: "2em" }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.expand
{
    height: 2em;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I've also try using .css in JS and trying to add icon, but I suppose I don't do this right way, cause nothing gets shown.

```
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500);
        $(this).css('glyphicon glyphicon-camera');
    });
```

Textarea should behave like this:

OnFocusOut:

[image]

OnFocus:

[image]

Can someone help me, and give me an idea on how to do this...Because I'm pretty bad in JS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ftrjoyy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Simple answer can be creating a sibling div element to the textarea which will contain all the icons, show the div of focusing the textarea and hide it on focusout of the textarea

Answer (score 1):

This example is using the selector

```
.parent:hover .links{}
```

but could be edited to

```
.parent:focus .links{}
```

if desired. However, to show you this in action, i've designed a simple demo below:

```css
.parent{
  height:100px;
  width:70%;
  background:red;  
  position:relative;
  }

.parent:hover .links{
  display:block;
  }

.links{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

    <div class="links">
      facebook twitter etc
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## An example using Sibling selectors

Here is a working example of using the sibling selector

```
input:focus + .items
```

which selects the class .items of which has a sibling of 'input' which has a focus (i.e. what you're looking for)

```css
#parent{
  height:100px;
  width:80%;
  background:red;
  position:relative;  
}

.items{  
  bottom:0;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

 input:focus + .items{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter text"/>
  <div class="items">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20" alt=""/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20" alt=""/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```